# How to restrict a command to a role in another server | Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so that a user needs a role in another server to use a specific command.

I know how to restrict a command to a role in the server the command was used in but no idea how to make it out of server.

Could I get some help or at-least a step in the right direction

Comment: Do you mean, for example, only someone with, for example the admin role, can use the command?

Comment: @Pepe_Worm No, I'm trying to limit the command to people who have a specific role in _another_ server (that the bot is in of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the server the role they need is in and check if the user has it there. Keep in mind that the client needs to be in both servers.

```
// Guild the user needs to have the role in
let guildA = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD ID");

// Role that the user needs
let requiredRole = guildA.roles.cache.get("ROLE ID");

// Member object of the user in guildA
let member = guildA.members.cache.get(message.author.id);

// Check if they have the role 
if (member.roles.cache.has(requiredRole.id)) {
    message.channel.send("You have the required role.");
} else {
    message.channel.send("You do not have the required role");
};
```

'ROLE ID' and 'GUILD ID' are the ID's of the role the user needs, and the server the role is in.

EDIT: This code is for discord.js v12. Anything lower and you have to remove all instances of 'cache', e.g `guildA.members.cache.get` -> `guildA.members.get`

Comment: I'm getting an error:

'TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined' for the "let guildA = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD ID");" part

Am I missing something?

Comment: @Max Which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 11.5.1

Comment: Did a bit of research and I just had to remove the "cache" part to make it version 11 compatible. Thanks

Comment: Yep, was about to suggest doing that if you said anything lower than v12. Sorry for not specifying the version in my answer.